# Using REGEXP in SQL syntax with concatenated PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, regex

I have this table where in it store the score and based on each category. The data store in this format, "_bestscore_category1_user1", the title of the stats, the name of the category, and the user. As you can see they are delimited by underscore.

```
Table
---------------------------------------- 
User                       | Score
_bestscore_category1_user1 |  10
_bestscore_category1_user2 |  20
_bestscore_category2_user2 |  20
_bestscore_category2_user1 |  5
```

So the problem is that, Im trying to query the field based on the user, my sql statement is like this.

```
SELECT meta_value from wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key REGEXP '_bestscore_([^=])_". $user."'
```

As you can see we have variable $user which is dynamic, trying this sql, gives me a null output. I wonder if my sql is incorrect, I did try to validate it, but null is the value I'm getting. Any idea?

Note: SQL statement, is not related to the table,

Comment: Try changing the regex to `_bestscore_([^_]*)_`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT meta_value from wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key REGEXP '_bestscore_.*?_". $user."'
```

this will solve your problem.